# Find Class Members which are Not Other Classes in C# Net Core with Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-core, .net-core-2.0

I am trying to use reflection, and iterating through all Class members. How to tell if a member is not another class or regular system item(int, boolean, Datetime, string,etc)?

```
assembly.GetTypes().GetProperties.

PropertyType.BaseType
```

String is showing as Value Object, along with Manufacturer class. Trying to detect all non-classes regular system data types.  How can this be done with reflection properties?

```
    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductDescription{ get; set; }
        public bool? Active { get; set; }
        public float SalesPrice { get;set;}
        public DateTime? EffectiveStartDate { get; set; }
        public Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public Department Department {get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ProductHistory> {get; set; }
    }
```

Using Net Core 2,

Comment: What do you mean " if a member is not another class"? What kind of "not another class"? Please elaborate in detail or give a sample type on "not another class",

Comment: Manufacturer and Department is another class in example, etc,  ProductId, SalesPrice, Description, Active, StartDate  are int, float, string, boolean, date respectively, and don't refer to other classes  @EriawanKusumawardhono

Answer (score 1):

About .NET Core reflection, you must know that in old versions you need to use [`Type.GetTypeInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.introspectionextensions.gettypeinfo?view=netcore-1.0). This is no longer true for .NET Core 2.0 and newer. However if you are multi-targeting I suggest to keep using `Type.GetTypeInfo()`.

---

To identify classes, I suggest to check [`Type.IsValueType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isvaluetype?view=netcore-2.0). Or for old .NET Core platforms use [`TypeInfo.IsValueType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.typeinfo.isvaluetype?view=netcore-1.0).

Classes and delegates are not value types. While structs and enums are.

Of course, you can also use [`Type.IsClass`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isclass?view=netcore-2.0) or [`TypeInfo.IsClass`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.typeinfo.isclass?view=netcore-1.0). *Which also return true for delegates.*

To distinguish delegates you can use `typeof(Delegate).IsAssignableFrom(type)` or `typeof(Delegate).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(type)`.

*By the way, `string` is a class.*

---

We should also consider interface types such as `ICollection<T>`. an [`interface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) could be implemented by a class or a struct.

The interface type is neither, it is an interface. You can use [`Type.Isinterface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isinterface?view=netcore-2.0) or [`TypeInfo.IsInterface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.typeinfo.isinterface?view=netcore-1.0) to check for it.

You might check other properties such as [`IsArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isarray?view=netcore-2.0), [`IsPrimitive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isprimitive?view=netcore-2.0), [`IsEnum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isenum?view=netcore-2.0), etc.

---

However, I suspect, what you want isn't to distinguish classes, but to distinguish *your* types. In that case you have a couple options:

You could check the namesapce ([`Type.Namespace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.namespace?view=netcore-1.0)). You are not placing your types in `System`, are you? Well, check that.

Alternatively you can check the `Assembly` from [`TypeInfo.Assembly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.typeinfo.assembly?view=netcore-1.0) or [`Type.Assembly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.assembly?view=netcore-2.0) in modern .NET Core. If you have a type of which you know it is in your assembly, you can get the assembly from it, and use it to compare the assembly of other types.

Of course, you can still check `IsValueType` or `IsClass` if you really do not want any `struct` or `enum`.

Comment: this is interesting, for this  Collection on a Class, its saying Type.IsClass is false,  maybe because its a collection?    public virtual ICollection<ProductHistory> ProductHistory{ get; set; }

Comment: btw, I was looking at Entity Framework Core 2.2 scaffold items, by the way, and looking at ICollection on classes

Comment: @MattSmith74 ah, forgot about that, `ICollection<ProductHistory>` is not a class, it is an [interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) type. It could be implemented by a class or a struct, the interface type is neither, it is an interface. You can use `Type.Isinterface` or `TypeInfo.IsInterface` to check for it. You might also be interested in other properties such as `IsArray`, `IsPrimitive`, `IsEnum`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, based on your last comment reply, I think I understand your question now.

To get all properties that are categorized as non .NET types (a.k.a. non .NET Base Class Library (BCL) types), you can simply filter the result of `assembly.GetTypes().GetProperties()`.

A quick sample is by using LINQ:

```cs
var proplist = assembly.GetTypes().GetProperties();
var proplistNonBCL = proplist.Where(prop => !prop.PropertyType.FullName.StartsWith("System.").ToList();
```

So basically it checks for the fullname of the underlying types. If the types' full name starts with "System.", then the types are not part of .NET BCL at all.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this.

```
 // object here referres to any object you are inspecting
        var props = Object.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var p in props)
        {
            if (p.PropertyType.IsValueType)
            {
                // This is not a class
            }
        }
```

Comment: well this needs to account for strings, which are not value types

Comment: perhaps adding `|| p.PropertyType.GetType() == typeof(string)' to the condition to get past strings..